# Condition for a number to be in range - Titanium/Javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I'm developing app in Titanium using Javascript and trying to realize the following check logic:
User has entered one value in range between 1 and 200, then he/she should enter second value in range between 1 and the first value(less or equal, but no more then the first value).

Here is my code:

```
var value_alert = '';  //First value
var value_remind = ''; //Second value (should be less or equal)

var default_value_alert = 10; //Default first value for TextField
var default_value_remind = 5; //Default second value for TextField

// handle and save the first value entered by user
function doOpenAlert(){ 

     var input_text = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD
    });

    if(value_alert === ''){
        input_text.value = default_value_alert;       

    } else {
        input_text.value = value_alert;  
    }

    var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
       title : "Specified distance in the range 1-200 km",
       androidView : input_text,
       buttonNames : ['Ok', 'Cancel'] 
    });
    dialog.show();    
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        if(value_remind === ''){
            value_remind = default_value_remind;       
        } 

        if(e.index == 0){  // Check is Ok pressed
            // check_number = isInt(input_text.value);

            if(input_text.value >= 1 && input_text.value <= 200){ // Check that the first value is in range
                var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                    duration: 2000,
                    message: "Distance is " + input_text.value + " km."
                });
                toast.show();
                value_alert = input_text.value; // Saving the first value entered by user
            } else if(input_text.value == 0){
                alert("The field is empty.");
            } else if(!(input_text.value >= 1 && input_text.value <= 200)){
                alert("Range is between 1 and 200 km.");
            } 
        }
    });
}

// handle and save the second value entered by user 
function doOpenMinne(){

    var input_text = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD  
    });

    if(value_remind === ''){
        input_text.value = default_value_remind;
    } else {
        input_text.value = value_remind;
    }

    var dialog = Ti.UI.createOptionDialog({
       title : "Remind before number", 
       androidView : input_text,
       buttonNames : ['Ok', 'Cancel'] 
    });
    dialog.show();
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){

        if(value_alert === ''){
            value_alert = default_value_alert;       
        } 

        if(e.index == 0){
            // check_number = isInt(input_text.value);
            if(input_text.value >= 1 && input_text.value <= value_alert){ // Check if the second value in is range between 1 and the first value
                 var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
                    duration: 2000,
                    message: "Remind at " + input_text.value + " km."
                });
                toast.show();
                value_remind = input_text.value; // Saving the second value entered by user
            } else if(input_text.value == 0){
                alert("The field is empty");
            } else if(!(input_text.value >= 1 && input_text.value <= 200)){
                alert("The range is between 1 and 200 km");
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

For example, it works well in the following combination:
1)
First value - 10;
Second value - 5;

2)
First value - 105;
Second value - 101;

And the main thing, if the first value is >= 100 , but the second is < 100 - **it doesn't work**.

It seems that conditions are correct, but works incorrect - can't find a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue you're having is that you're comparing the values as strings rather than numbers. When you compare two strings, [Javascript bases the comparison on the Unicode values of the characters in order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). What does that mean for you? The short answer is, that while `"90" < 200` is `true` because that comparison results in the `"90"` being coerced to `90`, `"90" < "200"` is `false` because `"9"` is greater than `"2"`.

In order to avoid this behavior, you need to convert one or both of your variables to numbers. [This answer on converting strings into numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/2280630) shows a number of ways for you to do that, but in your case, I think that `parseInt(input_text.value, 10) <= parseInt(value_alert, 10)` would work fine for you.

Comment: Thank you Evan! You are right - different types. Now it works correctly.